# How can I set the specific selected date to min date in android date picker? (java)

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar, mindate

I have 2 DatePickers, one is start date picker and the other is end date picker. I want to set the min date of the end DatePicker to the start date which user has selected.

I set the Data which user selected in Calander startDate and set this data as MinDate at end date.
I've tried in this way but it's not working :(

I can't use Mateiral Range Date Picker because I have to use specific theme.
Also I'm not good at programming so I'd appreciate it if you could explain it in detail.

```
ipDcEventStartDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        startYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        startMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        startDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(DoubleCheckEventActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                startYear = year;
                startMonth = month+1;
                startDay = dayOfMonth;

                ipDcEventStartDay.setText(startYear + " - " + startMonth + " - " + startDay);
                ipDcEventStartDay.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }
        }, startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        dpd.show();
    }
});

Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
startDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, startYear);
startDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, startMonth);
startDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startDay);

ipDcEventEndDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        endYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        endMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        endDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(DoubleCheckEventActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                endYear = year;
                endMonth = month;
                endDay = dayOfMonth;

                ipDcEventEndDay.setText(endYear + " - " + (endMonth+1) + " - " + endDay);
                ipDcEventEndDay.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }
        }, endYear,endMonth, endDay);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startDate.getTimeInMillis());
        dpd.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your implementation of min and max date? Maybe there is some problem there, because those are the methods used. I suposse you already check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android)

Comment: @javdromero Those codes are all I did.. I set the end date Date Picker to `dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startDate.getTimeInMillis());
        dpd.show();`

Comment: Don’t post [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67074925/how-can-i-set-the-specific-selected-date-to-min-date-in-android-date-picker) again. Instead edit your previous question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
startDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, startYear);
startDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, startMonth);
startDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startDay);
```

Should be inside

```
ipDcEventEndDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

Because `startYear`, `startMonth` and `startDay` are only set on `ipDcEventStartDay.setOnClickListener()`, so at the beginning they have some value but not the one that was set on `ipDcEventStartDay.setOnClickListener()`

So in `ipDcEventEndDay.setOnClickListener()` you have to set again on `startDate` the values that were picked on the other `DatePickerDialog`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand :) Can I ask you one more question? I want to convert that startDate and endDate Calendar value to string. I add this code just after that ipDcEventDay.setOnClickLister { ... } but both startDate and endDate logged 00021231

Comment: This is my code what I tried `Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDate.set(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        Date start = startDate.getTime();
        Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDate.clear();
        endDate.set(endYear,endMonth,endDay);
        Date end = endDate.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String startDay = simpleDateFormat.format(start);
        String endDay = simpleDateFormat.format(end);
        Log.d("start",startDay);
        Log.d("end",endDay);`

Comment: Please put that code on the question as an edit, it's not understandable in a comment, also you can simple convert using `startDate.getTime().toString()`